# Why cant the system find the file that is specified?

Tags: java, operating-system, single-threaded

in the assignment, the code is suppose to print on a single word from each file that repeats the most. I used a path to get to the list of files used for this assignment and i put them into an array. i cannot seems to find the problem as the array has all the files in it set to string. So why cant it find my file?

below is my code for single thread:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;



public class SingleThreaded  {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File directoryPath = new File("C:\\assignment 3\\links");
        String[] dir = directoryPath.list();

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(dir));
        
        String result;
        //Scanner scan;

        //try{
            //Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

            long startTime = System.nanoTime();

            for (String file : dir) {
                //if(file.isFile()){

                    //BufferedReader inputStream = null;
                    String line;
                    
                    //int i;

                    try{
                        
                        //inputStream = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));file

                        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(file));

                        HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

                        while (scan.hasNextLine()){
                            
                            line = scan.nextLine().replaceAll("\\p{Punct}", " ");
                            String[] word = line.split("\s+");
                                
                            for (int i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {

                                String string = word[i].toLowerCase();

                                if (string.length() >= 5) {

                                    if (map.containsKey(string)) {

                                        map.put(string, map.get(string) + 1);

                                    } else {

                                        map.put(string, 1);

                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        result = Collections.max(map.entrySet(), Comparator.comparingInt(Map.Entry::getValue)).getKey();
                        
                        System.out.println( file + ": " + result);

                    }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                   /* }finally{

                        if(inputStream != null){
                            inputStream.close();
                        }
                    }
                    */ 
               // }                           
            }
        long endTime = System.nanoTime();
        long totalTime = (endTime - startTime)/1000;     
        System.out.print("Total Time: " + totalTime);
        
        //} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            //e.printStackTrace();
        //}
    }
}
```

I tried changing the path and using different built-in methods but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Most likely it isn't there. (My first guess would be that the file has an extension that your file browser is hiding.)

Comment: `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(dir));` -  what is the output of this statement?

Comment: @ChristophDahlen it prints out all the files in that links folder

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- like what? when i used a buffered reader it printed out the files and the words but not the way it was suppose to print.

Comment: So, it cannot read one of the files in directory C:\assignment 3\links?

Comment: @ChristophDahlen none of them. it throws out a FileNotFoundException

Comment: From the docs of java.io.File.list(): „  Each string [returned] is a file name rather than a complete path.“. So, you are missing the base directory path when trying to read the files.

Comment: @ChristophDahlen wouldnt the ```new Scanner(new File(file))``` retrieve the file path?

Comment: It cannot resolve a relative file name (myfile.txt) to an absolute location without a context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

  File directoryPath = new File("C:\\assignment 3\\links");
  File[] files = directoryPath.listFiles();

  for (File file : files) {

   Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
```

Notice the difference, using File.listFiles() instead of File.list().

Comment: i had used this earlier and it kept throwing an error saying that ```new Scanner(new File(file)`` it needed to receive a String[] as input "constructor File(file) is undefined"

Comment: Sorry, fixed my answer, we can use the file from the list directly with Scanner.